# Clean and Read csv file with pandas which has unwanted texts

Tags: python, pandas

I have large number of csv files (More than 10K)  and all files have unwated texts at start and end .I want to clean the csv file first and then read it . One of the example is like below (Below is a sample data ,my csv files are similar to below . I need to clean and ignore all the texts above

Columns for reference are : Student,id,add,div,rank

```
SAMPLE FILE LTD

STUDENT NUMBERS

INFO OF ALL STUDENTS No :  from 27-Mar-2023 00:00:00 to 04-Apr-2023 00:00:00 and  from 05-Oct-2023 00:00:00 to 13-Oct-2023 00:00:00

Student,id,add,div,rank
ABC,12,USA,A,1
DEF,13,IND,C,2
XYZ,14,UK,E,3
PQR,15,DE,F,4


 This is System generated report, and needs no signature.

 14-Oct-2023 18:14:12
```

One solution which I found is as below

```
#This will read the file untill the filter value is reached 

def get_rows_to_skip(file_name,filter):
    rows=0;
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if filter in  line:
            return rows
        rows=rows+1

def read_csv():
    skiprows=0
    is_check=True
    file_name="/Users/test/Desktop/student/students.csv"
    rows=get_rows_to_skip(file_name,"rank")
    df=pd.read_csv(file_name,skiprows=rows)
    df = df[df['rank'].notna()]

    print("done")
```

Comment: Did you try something like `pd.read_csv(data, skiprows=7, skipfooter=5)`?

Comment: Well some files might not have the unwanted text and some files might even have just 1-2 rows of unwanted text . Its not a guarantee .

Comment: maybe check the length of a row's text content, if its long and the use it in `skiprows=check_rows_text_leng' ?

Comment: something `def is_short_row(row, max_length=80):
    return len(' '.join(map(str, row))) <= max_length

max_row_length = 80 
df = pd.read_csv(data, skiprows=lambda x: not is_short_row(x, max_row_length))`

Comment: All the csv files have the `Student,id,add,div,rank` columns and no others?

Comment: Yes all files will have same column names

Comment: I updated my question with one solution

Comment: your solutions seems OK and you don't need anything more.

Comment: first you could read documentation for `read_csv`. It seems `skiprows` allows to use `function` to decide which rows to skip. Maybe this could be useful

Comment: Thank you @furas , excellent advice ,will read the documentation .

Comment: @nisakova the skiprows function only receives a line number as a parameter (try `pd.read_csv(skiprows = lambda x:print(x))` and you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to read the entire csv into a dataframe as lines, split the column on comma and drop lines with `NaN` values, then copy the first row to the column names and reset the index:

```
with open('students.csv', 'r') as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame(file.read().split('\n'))

df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True).dropna()

df, df.columns = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True), df.iloc[0].values
```

Output (for your sample file data):

```
  Student  id  add div rank
0     ABC  12  USA   A    1
1     DEF  13  IND   C    2
2     XYZ  14   UK   E    3
3     PQR  15   DE   F    4
```

Another possibility is to read lines from the file until you encounter the header, then `read_csv` the rest of the file, dropping rows with `NaN`:

```
with open('students.csv', 'r') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while not line.startswith('Student'):
        line = file.readline()
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=line.strip().split(',')).dropna()
```

Output:

```
  Student  id  add div  rank
0     ABC  12  USA   A   1.0
1     DEF  13  IND   C   2.0
2     XYZ  14   UK   E   3.0
3     PQR  15   DE   F   4.0
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `convert_dtypes` to infer the type of each column.

Comment: @Corralien interestingly that doesn't help at all. The `id` column just gets converted to a string, not an integer as you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect interesting parts based on the number of separators on each line. A generic way to do this is:

```
import mmap
import io
import pandas as pd


def read_csv(filename, *, sep=',', **kwargs):
    with (
        open(filename, mode='rb') as fp,
        mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm
    ):
        count = []
        start = 0
        for row in iter(mm.readline, b''):
            end = mm.tell()
            count.append((row.count(sep.encode()), start, end))
            start = end

        # Detection
        df = pd.DataFrame(count, columns=['count', 'start', 'end'])
        cnt = df.query('count > 0').value_counts('count').idxmax()
        start, end = df.query('count == @cnt').agg({'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'})
        df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(mm[start:end]), sep=sep, **kwargs)
    return df

df = read_csv('students.csv')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Student  id  add div  rank
0     ABC  12  USA   A     1
1     DEF  13  IND   C     2
2     XYZ  14   UK   E     3
3     PQR  15   DE   F     4

>>> df.dtypes()
Student    object
id          int64
add        object
div        object
rank        int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is definitely a more robust solution with regards to getting the right types in the final result.